# how to fix the number of rows in empty table in reporting service

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence

1. I am using business intelligence to create a report for your company, we need to add blank table for user to input information, when I add a table from toolbox to the report, it just shows 1 row, but after I preview the report, the report generate 10-20 of blank rows randomly, how can I set the number of row ?
2. When there is no records in table, how can I make the report to show "no records" ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Pls show any code, this is very hard to answer

Comment: Reports are not for user input. They are for *reporting*.

Comment: Just to leave blank space, any alternatives

Answer (score 0):

1. In the report designer, you will see 1 detail row (plus a header and footer row). In preview mode, you will see 1 detail row *per record* in the data source.
2. Use the "NoRows" property of the table to display a message when there are no rows. If this property is empty, the table header and footer will be displayed.